# Entity agnostic way of retrieving title

Tags: 8, entities

Is there a way of the Title/Label/Name of an unknown entity type via 1 method?

At the moment if it's a node, I have to use `$entity->getTitle()`, for a user it's `$entity->getAccountName()`, for a taxonomy term it'd be `$entity->getName()`

In my head they all feel like the same piece of information, is there a way of retrieving it without having to write out possibilities for each type of entity?

Comment: You use `$entity->label()`.

Comment: Perfect! I knew there must be a way of doing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All entity types, content and config both, have a `label()` method (see [`EntityInterface::label()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3Alabel/9.3.x)).

```
$label = $entity->label();
```

You can use this reliably on any entity. The entity classes themselves (Node, Term, etc) define the most appropriate value, so for nodes you get the title field, for terms you get the name field, and so on.